# Prove that the ratio of the areas of the two triangles thus formed tends to $4$ as the arc $AB$ decreases indefinitely.

Tags: geometry, limits

At the end points and the midpoint of a circular arc $AB$ tangent lines are drawn, and the points $A$ and $B$ are joined with a chord. Prove that the ratio of the areas of the two triangles thus formed tends to 4 as the arc $AB$ decreases indefinitely.

I attempted this question. Let the circle is centered at $O$, let the midpoint of the arc be M,let angle $AOB=2\theta$, therefore, angle $AOM=$ angle $BOM=\theta$, let the tangent at $A$ and the tangent at $M$ meet at point $T$, let the tangent at B and tangent at $M$ meet at $S$, therefore we need to find the limit of area of $ATM$/area of $BSM$ as $\theta \to 0$

But then I stuck, I cannot express areas in terms of $\theta$.

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Which two triangles are you speaking of?

Comment: The triangles $ATM$ and $BSM$ are congruent, aren't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangles $AMB, MSB, ATM$ are isosceles and the latter two are congruent while all are similar:  $\angle BMA =\pi-\angle AMT-\angle SMB=\angle MTA$. Therefore $$\frac{\text{area of }BAM}{\text{area of }MAT}=\frac{AB^2}{AM^2}.$$
As $AM:AB\to 1:2$, the limit of the quotient is $4$. (To make $AM:AB\to 1:2$ more precise, you may notice that $\frac{AB}{AM}=2\sin\frac12\angle AMB$ and $\angle AMB\to \pi$).

Answer (score 1):

Call $C$ the intersection of the tangent lines in $A$ and $B$. Set $AB=2x$, we want to know what happens to the ratio of the $2$ relevant triangles when $x\to 0$. Call $M$ the midpoint of the segment $AB$ and $N$ the foot of the height of the smaller triangle from $C$ (so $C,N,M$ are on a line). Also call $O$ the center of the circumference (let's say of radius $1$) of which $AB$ is a chord. Then $OM=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ by Pythagora, $CM=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ by Euclid, $CO=\frac{1}{OM}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ by Euclid and so $CN=CO-1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}-1$. In other words $$\frac{CM}{CN}=\frac{x^2}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$ and so we want $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x^2}{1-(1-\frac{1}{2}x^2)}=\lim_{x\to 0}=2.$$ The ratio of the areas is the square of the ratio of the sides, that is $2^2=4$.